# Azure OAUTH V1 retirement date

Tags: azure, oauth

It is well documented that Azure is retiring MS Graph API and ADAL libraries.  It is not clear whether or not Azure OAUTH V1 implementation will be retired as well at some point.  If anyone has insights on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS has confirmed that there is no official date for retiring OAUTH V1.  IF a date is announced, it will be three years after the announcement date